# Customizing Header and Footer of Table View with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I need to make a custom header for my tableview. for this I created a class of UITableViewHeaderFooterView type, but I can not select the header of the tableview on the storyboard to set up the class. if it were a static table header appear, but it is not visible to dynamic tables. How can I make this setting?

Note: I use xcode 7.3.1

I'm trying to do something like this, but the storyboard:
https://github.com/jeantimex/ios-swift-collapsible-table-section

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let header = tableView.dequeueReusableHeaderFooterViewWithIdentifier("header") as! NovaListaTableViewHeader


    header.titleLabel.text = sections[section].name
    header.arrowLabel.text = ">"
    header.setCollapsed(sections[section].collapsed)

    header.section = section
    header.delegate = self

    return header
}
```

Comment: share your code and share similar questions you read on Stackoverflow. Otherwise your question would get flagged very soon. :|

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do that. Most of do that by programatically  and some achieve it via storyboard and program.

so its totally depends on you how you want to achieve it.

I can share a easiest way with you to customise your header and footer section.

if you have good control on storyboard try to create one

```
UITableViewCell
```

Now decorate it as you want and in identifier Name it SectionHeader now use it as reuse cell

After that use this Delegate Method i am sharing an objective C delegate,

```
        override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {


var headerView: SectionHeaderTableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("SectionHeader")
  if (headerView == nil) {
    headerView = SectionHeaderTableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle, reuseIdentifier:"SectionHeader")
  }
  headerView!.textLabel!.text = "Hello World"


            return headerView;

        }
```

now do same thing for footer.

Comment: this isn't working for me in Xcode 8.3.3 and Mac OS 10.12.4

Comment: you forgot to mention that `SectionHeaderTableViewCel`l should subclass `UITableViewHeaderFooterView `

Comment: Don't forget to override the method height for header in section, otherwise you don't see anything by default since, by default return 0. So add something like:  `override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 60
    }`